# lost all remote repo data after git clone

Tags: git

We are not very experienced with git and just hit a very strange situation after a year of smoothness.

I asked our new intern to clone our remote repo, which he did with **'git clone remotename**'.

Right after that, our remote repo seems to have lost all its content!

when I clone it, I get an empty repo. **git log** shows a single commit with the message ":space_invader: Added .gitattributes & .gitignore files"

I didn't think it was possible to destroy a remote repo with a clone command and I'm not sure how to recover from this. I also don't know how to tell if the remote still has our code but has been lost due to pointers or some other problem. I'm not seeing any other posts here about a situation like this.

I can create a new remote repo from my local copy, but id still like to understand what happened and I would prefer to fix the existing repo before I replace it with a new one.

(If it makes a difference, we are using git on Windows machines. we connect to our remote repo through the file system, not https/ssh. we use the git desktop app and powershell.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is his clone valid? Also, no, it's not possible to clobber a remote repo with a clone command.

Answer (score 1):

Right after writing this I was able to reproduce this problem and I think I figured out what happened.

Using the GitHub Desktop app, he intended to **Add** the repo but the dialog default is **Create**.

If you try to create over an existing repo on the file system, the GUI gives an error but if you are using a network drive, it does not seem to catch the problem. So he accidentally created a new repo on top of our remote shared repo, which starts with the 1 checkin I mentioned above.

I assume there is no way to repair/recover the old remote so I will create a new shared remote.

Comment: You should report the bug to GitHub (if it hasn't been reported already).